# Using `foo` inside definition of `bar::foo`?

Tags: c++, namespaces

How can I refer to a function `foo` without a namespace from within a namespace `bar` that has already declared that same function `foo` (also the same arguments)?

### Minimal example

```
int foo(int x) { // base function
    return 2*x; // multiplies input by 2
}

namespace bar {
    float foo(int x) { // same function
        return (float)foo(x); // uses same math of original, but returns a float
    }
}
```

I could of course rename `bar::foo`, but since there can be no ambiguity problem outside the namespace, I don't want to and like to keep it simple for any user.

---

### Context

I'm trying to redefine `tan` to return a vector instead of a number (thus also the x-value). Here is a simplified version of what I want to do.

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES // enables mathematical constants
#include <cmath> // tan

template <typename T>
struct Vector2 { // simple Vector2 struct
    T x,y;
};

namespace v2 {
    template <typename T>
    Vector2<T> tan(T angle) { // redefine tan to return a Vector2
        Vector2<T> result;
        if (-90 < angle && angle < 90)
            result.x = 1;
        else
            result.x = -1;
        result.y = tan(angle); // <-- refers to v2::tan instead of tan
        return result;
    }
}

int main() {
    double          tangens  = tan(3.*M_PI_4); // M_PI_4 = pi/4
    Vector2<double> tangens2 = v2::tan(3.*M_PI_4); // <-- no ambiguity possible

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `::foo(x)` to jump to the top-level scope

Comment: That did the job! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function "without a namespace" actually belongs to *global* namespace. You can refer to it as `::foo`.

Answer (score 5):

You need to reference the type by explicitly providing it's scope. In this case the version of `foo` you are trying to call resides in the global namespace so you access it like so...

```
::foo(x);
```

To apply this to your code...

```
namespace bar
{
    float foo(int x)
    { // same function
        return (float)::foo(x); // uses same math of original, but returns a float
                   // ^^ scope qualified name
    }
}
```